# Silverstripe custom search into members dataobject

Tags: search, filtering, silverstripe

I have a little problem resolving getting SilverStripe 3.1 Fulltextsearchable running good for my usage. I retrieve some informations from Member dataobject and I create Links and Titles to show them on Page_search.ss template.

There is my code working but... **bad search filtering** :

```
public function results($data, $form){
    $data = $_REQUEST; 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($data['Search'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); 
    $PageMembres = Member::get()->filter('NomOrganisme',$query);

    $searchresults = new ArrayList();

    foreach($PageMembres as $membre) {
        if ($membre->Type==1) { $dir="repertoire-culturel/organismes-entreprises/details/"; }
        if ($membre->Type==2) { $dir="repertoire-culturel/individus-artistes/details/"; }

        $searchresults->push(

                array(  "Title" => $membre->NomOrganisme,
                            "link" => $membre->ID,    
                            "Link" => Director::BaseURL().$dir.$membre->ID,    
                            "URL" => $membre->ID,    

                )
        );

    }



    if($searchresults){ 
        $data['Results'] = $searchresults;           
    } else { 
        $data['Results'] = ''; 
    } 

    $data['Title'] = 'Résultat(s) de recheche'; 

    return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Page_results','Page')); 
}
```

So I that point, I need to change :

```
 $PageMembres = Member::get()->filter('NomOrganisme',$query);
```

For a more **complexe research** like :

```
 $PageMembres = DataObject::get("Member","MATCH (NomOrganisme,FirstName,Surname,Description) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

What I have missed with the complexe query? Why It doesn't works?
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can't use MATCH query on DataObject Member. There is my complexe working code that I use and works :

```
$PageMembres = Member::get()->where("
        FirstName LIKE '%$query%' OR
        Surname LIKE '%$query%' OR
        Description LIKE '%$query%' OR
        NomOrganisme LIKE '%$query%'");
```